# Installation of MP-OLSR in NS2.35

Tags: 16.04

Please sir, I want to install MP-OLSR on NS2.35. I'm looking for it already and no luck so far
I tried the following code:

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz

cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < mpolsr_umolsr-v1_ns235.patch
        ### Ubuntu
export CC=gcc447 CXX=g++447
        ### Fedora, RHEL, CentOS
export CC=gcc44 CXX=g++44
./install
cd ns-2.35/
cp ns ns235-mpolsr
sudo cp ns235-mpolsr /usr/local/bin/
```

but I found it problem during the installation:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-gcc
checking whether to use symlinks for manpages... no
checking whether to compress the manpages... no
checking whether to add a package name suffix for the manpages... no
checking for gcc... gcc44
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/ubunto/Pratique/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
tcl8.5.10 configuration failed! Exiting ...
Tcl is not part of the ns project.  Please see www.Scriptics.com
to see if they have a fix for your platform.
```

Please help me to solve this problem
Thank you sir .

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)

Comment: Do you *actually* have a `gcc44` installed, or are you just blindly following someone else's recipe?

Comment: yes it is installed

Comment: Your text says " ### Ubuntu : `export CC=gcc447 CXX=g++447 && ./install` "